# How to launch textadept on macos x in curses mode

Tags: macos, terminal, editor

I studied all the [manual](https://foicica.com/textadept/manual.html) about Textadept but still don't understand how from a command line in Terminal start Textadept in terminal aka curses mode.

I wish it be something like:

> textadept -g(ui) somefile.txt

starts editor in GUI mode

> textadept -c(onsole) somefile.txt

starts editor in curses mode

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create an alias somewhere in a directory that is on your path, for example ~/.local/bin:

```
ln -s /Users/{your usename}/Applications/Textadept.app/Contents/MacOS/textadept-curses textadept-c
```

(Assuming you have Textadept installed in ~/Applications

Then you can launch it as

```
textadept-c somefile.txt
```

Comment: For the GUI call you might want to copy the file at 
https://foicica.com/hg/textadept/file/5e4d1b5d4a72/scripts/osx/ta
and adjust it to your paths.